# Apache Flink reduce results in many values instead of one

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to implement a reduce on a WindowedStream, like so:

```
                .keyBy(t -> t.key)
            .timeWindow(Time.of(15, MINUTES), Time.of(1, MINUTES))
            .reduce(new ReduceFunction<TwitterSentiments>() {
                @Override
                public TwitterSentiments reduce(TwitterSentiments t2, TwitterSentiments t1) throws Exception {
                    t2.positive += t1.positive;
                    t2.neutral += t1.neutral;
                    t2.negative += t1.negative;

                    return t2;
                }
            });
```

The problem I am having is that when I call stream.print(), I get many values (looks like one per TwitterSentiments object, instead of a single aggregate object.

I have also tried using an AggregationFunction like this, with the same issue:

```
                .aggregate(new AggregateFunction<TwitterSentiments, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> createAccumulator() {
                    return new Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>(0L,0L,0L);
                }

                @Override
                public Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> add(TwitterSentiments ts, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> accumulator) {
                    return new Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>(
                            accumulator.f0 + ts.positive.longValue(),
                            accumulator.f1 + ts.neutral.longValue(),
                            accumulator.f2 + ts.negative.longValue()
                    );
                }

                @Override
                public Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> getResult(Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> accumulator) {
                    return accumulator;
                }

                @Override
                public Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> merge(Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> accumulator1, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long> accumulator2) {
                    return new Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>(
                            accumulator1.f0 + accumulator2.f0,
                            accumulator1.f1 + accumulator2.f1,
                            accumulator1.f2 + accumulator2.f1);
                }
            });
```

What are the reasons why stream.print() would still output many records after these aggregations?

Comment: Probably you are using `EventTime`. Can you check the setting of `timeCharacteristic` for your streaming env(set by `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic`)? If you are using `EventTime`, then the time window is triggered by event time instead of local machine time.

Comment: @David Hmm, thanks for the answer, but it appears that's not the issue. the `timeCharacteristic` was set to `ProcessingTime` by default. I tried using `IngestionTime` and still have the same issue. What else could be going on here?

Comment: Ahhh, can you check the keys of output from print? Are they all different? For the same key, it must have more than 1 minute's interval in the print output(tumbling window).

Comment: You should be getting one result per key per minute. It would be easier to understand what's happening if your results included the key and the time -- you could accomplish this by passing the pre-aggregated results through a ProcessWindowFunction. See https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_java/windows/HourlyTipsSolution.java#L115 for an example.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Ah, "per key". That makes sense. Your answer helped me solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need a result per key, you can use timeWindowAll to produce a single result. However, timeWindowAll does not run in parallel. If you want to compute the result in a more scalable way, you can do this:

```
    .keyBy(t -> t.key)
    .timeWindow(<time specification>)
    .reduce(<reduce function>)
    .timeWindowAll(<same time specification>)
    .reduce(<same reduce function>)
```

You might expect Flink's runtime to be smart enough to do this parallel pre-aggregation for you (provided you are using a ReduceFunction or AggregateFunction), but it's not.

Comment: This does exactly what I was trying to do originally, thanks. I had created a keyed stream because I wanted parallel processing, but did not see that keyed streams also aggregated per-key. This now makes a lot more sense. You're right that I had expected flink to do this processing for me.

Comment: Hi, I did an example of that using `timeWindow -> process -> timeWindowAll -> reduce` and I am wondering if I can implement my own operator in Flink (using `SingleOutputStreamOperator`) to do it for me

Answer (score 2):

It appears I've misunderstood the reason why keys are used. In my case, I do not need a `KeyedStream`, as I desire only a single output per minute, which consists of all the records reduced to one value. I ended up using a `.timeWindowAll`, on a `SingleOutputStreamOperator`, and running my reduce now works as expected.